# how to realtime calculate values from input, checkbox, radio and selectbox

Tags: jquery

I want to make a realtime calculation in a form with several elements and immediately the `totalprice` should be displayed.
This is what i have so far:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        //function to calculate total
        var calculateTotal = function(){
        var total = (parseFloat($('.totaalbroodjegezond').text()) || 0.0 ) +
                  (parseFloat($('.totaalbroodjezalm').text()) || 0.0 ) +
                  (parseFloat($('.totaalbroodjetonijn').text()) || 0.0 ); 

        $('.totaalprijs').text(total);
        };

        // function for the checkboxes and radios
        $(".calculate").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        $(".calculate:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        if (total == 0) {
            $('.totaalprijs').text('');

        } else {                
            $('.totaalprijs').text(total);
                           }

    }); 


          // multiply price with values of input field
          $('#broodjegezond').keyup(function(){
          $('.totaalbroodjegezond').text($('#broodjegezond').val() * 2.5);
          calculateTotal();
          });
          $('#broodjezalm').keyup(function(){
          $('.totaalbroodjezalm').text($('#broodjezalm').val() * 3.5);
          calculateTotal();
          });
           $('#broodjetonijn').keyup(function(){
          $('.totaalbroodjetonijn').text($('#broodjetonijn').val() * 4.5);
          calculateTotal();
          });

});
```

The normal input fields work fine.`Checkboxes` and `RadioButtons` also work fine as standalone but I do not know how to integrate them in `calculateTotal()`
And I also need a function for the `selectbox`, and integrate that also in `calculateTotal()`. 
Can someone help me with these things?
So what i want to achieve: all form elements should be calculated in `calculateTotal()` and displayed in

```
<span class="totaalprijs"><span>
```

Below the form:

```
 <form class="bestelformulier" method="post" action=''>
    <table style="width:300px">
        <tr>
          <td>Broodje Gezond</td>
          <td>&euro; <?php echo $prijzen['broodjegezond']; ?></td>      
          <td><input name="broodjegezond" id="broodjegezond" type="text" placeholder="aantal" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>
          <td>&euro; <span class="totaalbroodjegezond"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Broodje Zalm</td>
          <td>&euro; <?php echo $prijzen['broodjezalm']; ?></td>        
          <td><input name="broodjezalm" id="broodjezalm" type="text" placeholder="aantal" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>
          <td>&euro; <span class="totaalbroodjezalm"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Broodje Tonijn</td>
          <td>&euro; <?php echo $prijzen['broodjetonijn']; ?></td>
          <td><input name="broodjetonijn" id="broodjetonijn" type="text" placeholder="aantal" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>
          <td>&euro; <span class="totaalbroodjetonijn"></span></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    checkbox value 10
    <input class="calculate" type="checkbox" value="10" />
    <br />
    Checkbox value 15
    <input class="calculate" type="checkbox" value="15" />
    <br />
    Checkbox value 20
    <input  class="calculate" type="checkbox" value="20" />
    <br />
    Checkbox value 25
    <input class="calculate" type="checkbox" value="25" />
    <br />

    <br /><br />

    Radio value 20
    <input class="calculate" type="radio" name="calculate-radio" value="20" />
    <br />
    Radio value 25
    <input class="calculate" type="radio" name="calculate-radio" value="25" />
    <br />
    Radio value 30
    <input class="calculate" type="radio" name="calculate-radio" value="30" />


    <br /><br />
    <select name="selectbox"  id="selectbox">
        <option value="Select One">Select One</option>
        <option value="10">Price 10</option>
        <option value="15">Price 15</option>
        <option value="20">Price 20</option>
    </select>

    <br /><br />
    <span>Totaalprijs: &euro;</span>
    <span class="totaalprijs"></span>


</form>
```

Comment: Use `.change()` for the checkboxes and select box.

Comment: i still do not get it work. How can i sum the values of the checkbox and radios with the other ones?

Comment: Add in `parseFloat($("#selectbox").val())` and use `$(".calculate:checked").each()` to add in all the checkbox/radio values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want one function that calculates all fields. This makes it a little easier to combine functionality. Then as suggested by Barmar you can use the `change` event (or in combination with `keyup`) and pass that one function to this event(s).

The function typically loops over each element, to check it's type and switch your calculation accordingly.

```
$.each(elements, function () {
    var field = $(this),
        newVal;

    // switch type
    switch (field.prop('type')) {
        case 'select-one':
            newVal = field.find(':selected').val() || 0;
            break;
        case 'text':
            newVal = parseFloat(field.val() || 0) * field.data('price');
            field.closest('td').next().find('span').text(newVal);
            break;
        case 'radio':
            newVal = this.checked ? field.val() : 0;
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            newVal = this.checked ? field.val() : 0;
            break;
    }

    newVal = parseFloat(newVal);
    total += newVal;
});
```

Looping over each field and using by default `0` values helps you to quickly calculate the summary. It could've stored each value separately in an array for example, but then you have to compare which field it originated from, in case of subtraction, and that makes it more cumbersome.

My advice is to loop over each field and take this little overhead.

Some small changes on the HTML part:

```
<!-- for text fields you can use a data attribute to store your php values -->
<input type="text" data-price="2.5" />

<!-- the select's first option value should be 0 -->
<option value="0">Select One</option>
```

Additionally restrict the user input for text fields to allow only numbers:

```
elements.filter('[data-price]').on('keypress', function (ev) {
    var key = ev.keyCode || ev.which;

    if (key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/zojdnywL/)**

Smakelijk ;)