# Using a reg expression to ensure the user entered a decimal?

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

I am trying to ensure that the user can only enter a decimal. I found a reg expression that checks for this, but it's seemingly working in the reverse of how I'd like it to. Right now if the user enters a non decimal the button on my form gets enabled. I want the button to get enabled only if the user enters a decimal.
Here is my code.

```js
            decimal: function (val/*,rule*/){
                if(!val){
                    return true;
                }
                return /^[0-9]{1,6}(?:[,.][0-9]{0,5})?$/.test(val);
            },
```

Comment: STOP! No regex! Capture the keyboard event before you are going to filter replace do stuff. check the demo in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543514/how-to-realtime-calculate-values-from-input-checkbox-radio-and-selectbox/29546405#29546405)

Comment: If your expression matches the regex it returns true. From what i can see, if you have no value you return true aswell. So you can do "return !regex.test(val);"

Answer (score 1):

Your function works fine. I suggest reversing the returning value like this:

```
decimal: function (val/*,rule*/){
    if(!val){
        return true;
    }
    return !/^[0-9]{1,6}(?:[,.][0-9]{0,5})?$/.test(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works to ensure the user has  entered a decimal value (upto 2 points (eg.785747.12))..

```
\d+(\.\d{1,2})?
```

I got this from 
[Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

I hope this helps.