# Backspace not working after last input JavaScript (java) in Mozilla.I am also unable to prevent character 'e' from the search box

Tags: javascript, html

```
function val()
{
    a=f1.t1.value;
    if(a.length>10)
        {
        alert("invalid");
        return false;
        }
    else
        return true;
}

function Filter(event) {

    var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

   var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (event.keycode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46
     || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || [8,9,37,39,46].indexOf(event.keyCode) !== -1 || e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)
     {
        return true;

    }

 isWanted = (keyCode>=48 && keyCode<=57);
    return isWanted;
}
HTML
<input type="number" onkeypress="return val()" onkeydown="return   Filter(event)" required><br><br><br
```

I used this code for restricting inputs in a 'type = number' html box(No characters allowed).It is restricting number of inputs ,but the backspace is not working ,after I input the last value(number). And also I am unable to prevent character 'e' in Mozilla browser.Please help.Also pl. tell me if I have called functions properly using HTML.

Comment: JavaScript != Java.

Comment: JavaScript (java) .. meaning ? Also what is `f1` & `t1` in the first line. I can't see them defined anywhere

Comment: For number restriction I can direct you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543514/how-to-realtime-calculate-values-from-input-checkbox-radio-and-selectbox/29546405#29546405) post. => `if (key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }`

Comment: f1 is form name,t1 is text box name

Comment: People I put it in the bracket to say that I am using java ! not ASP .NET.